# Python 2D array construction

Tags: python, arrays

The main problem is that the windowarea is not being appended as a matrix with rows and columns but as a row matrix.

```
i = int (raw_input ('Number of elevations:'))
elevationarea = []
windowarea = []
pureelevationarea = []

    for i in xrange(i):
       print ('Elevation ' + str(i+1))
       j = int(raw_input('Number of windows?:')) 
       H = float(raw_input('Height of elevation?:'))
       L = float(raw_input('Length of elevation?:'))
       elevationarea.append(H * L)

        for j in xrange(j):
            print ('Elevation ' + str(i+1))
            print ('Window ' + str(j+1))
            podia = float(raw_input('Podia parathirou?:'))
            preki = float(raw_input('Preki parathyrou?:'))
            mikosparathirou = float(raw_input('Mikos parathyrou?:'))
            embadonparathiron =(preki-podia)*mikosparathirou
            windowarea.append(embadonparathiron)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten a multiply sign there:

```
embadonparathiron =(preki * podia)*mikosparathirou
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define a 2d structure here so it is quite normal that you don't get a 2d structure... How would Python guess that you want 2d?

2 options for you: use numpy arrays or list of lists

for numpy you should start by reading any basic tutorial (not very hard to start and it is worth the little extra effort, numpy is great once you are familiar with it!)

for list of lists here is an example on how to do it:

```
matrix = []
for i in range(n_rows):
    new_row = []
    for j in range(n_cols):
        new_row.append(some_value)
    matrix.append(new_row)
```